# separating googletest test cases with cmake

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, googletest

I work on a project built with CMake that uses Google test for testing. The CMakeLists.txt file of my tests looks like this:

```
add_executable(run_tests
    testcase_a.cpp
    dependency_a.cpp
    testcase_b.cpp
    dependency_b.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(run_tests gtest gtest_main)
```

With growing number of test cases, this gets rather messy. I'd like to compile each of the testcases separately and then run them using a single binary. Can this be done using CMake and gtest_main? Or is there a better way of doing this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic idea:-

```
add_library(testcase_a.o OBJECT testcase_a.cpp dependency_a.cpp)
add_library(testcase_b.o OBJECT testcase_b.cpp dependency_b.cpp)   
add_executable(run_tests $<TARGET_OBJECTS:testcase_a.o> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:testcase_b.o>)
target_link_libraries(run_tests gtest gtest_main)
```

See [Object Libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_library.html#id4)

Comment: This looks like the solution I need. However, I can't get the run_tests executable to link properly - the libraries complain about missing references to gtest functions.

Comment: @Teyras If you can post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your linkage failure maybe I can see what's wrong. For now can only say it works for me. Be sure you've built your libgtest and libgtest_main with very same compiler that's building your `run_tests` now.

Comment: Well, a minimal setup seems to work. I'll mark your answer as correct and try to sort out my problems myself.